# Unable to tunnle to vmc mysql service due to memory limitation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry, tunnel, vmc

I am unable to tunnle to my free hosted instance of a rails app on cloudfoundry inftrastructure.

When I run 'vmc tunnel mysql-service', I get the below:

1: none
2: mysql
3: mysqldump
Which client would you like to start?> 2

Opening tunnel on port 10000... FAILED
CFoundry::AccountNotEnoughMemory: 600: Not enough memory capacity, you're allowed: 2048M
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

Checking the ~/.vmc/crash logs I see:

Time of crash:
  2013-03-13 18:16:54 -0400

CFoundry::AccountNotEnoughMemory: 600: Not enough memory capacity, you're allowed: 2048M

<<<
REQUEST: PUT https://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps/caldecott
REQUEST_HEADERS:
  Authorization : bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzNjM4MTc3OTgsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImhzdWVpbmczQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbImNsb3VkX2NvbnRyb2xsZXIucmVhZCIsIm9wZW5pZCIsInBhc3N3b3JkLndyaXRlIl0sImVtYWlsIjoiaHN1ZWluZzNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXVkIjpbIm9wZW5pZCIsImNsb3VkX2NvbnRyb2xsZXIiLCJwYXNzd29yZCJdLCJqdGkiOiJkMzZjNDI3MS02ZDJkLTRjN2EtOThmYS1kNzc2MjhiZDFiNmMiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiODY0OWZkMzEtY2JiNy00N2YyLTkyNmItODM5Y2MzNWFlMTlmIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoidm1jIn0.Lt1Bw7mBP55Hi9MIPTn90s0RXkJcJwGZXZcqDep4BBnnwjrAOAPQPGlIwBA-Ovy9K5BazMXqnQCOv8kxpK8o4wo3vG6RAJPvF7p76JgZDq0C_n_PUV1LaxGrldnpc2PLawR0FHHChb7tKCJP4cf26lK8A8vg5GEwi8HWO5OJCERI-3CKKiGJB5mVj2rWGmE39-ihAWmT5LpS5jAEZ-XVvo4VDEKknJ8SQC6693FzdCZ2AJBHkAgNxRoCsBtvkxOgKkspI-IkcaMZx884BT24cGbseZ5XY3bj6ZjAb499AfbIFe97Hme4axtpWo8qn1grkrJxyI3gmYAVMHVgo1M1IQ
  Content-Length : 310
  Content-Type : application/json
REQUEST_BODY: {"name":"caldecott","instances":1,"state":"STARTED","staging":{"model":"sinatra","stack":"ruby19"},"resources":{"memory":64,"disk":2048,"fds":256},"env":["CALDECOTT_AUTH=43ae7176-67f6-41ac-8cff-bf21b4249a49"],"uris":["caldecott-d9149.cloudfoundry.com"],"services":["mysql-service"],"console":null,"debug":null}
RESPONSE: [403]
RESPONSE_HEADERS:
  cache-control : no-cache
  connection : keep-alive
  content-type : application/json; charset=utf-8
  date : Wed, 13 Mar 2013 22:16:54 GMT
  keep-alive : timeout=20
  server : nginx
  transfer-encoding : chunked
  x-ua-compatible : IE=Edge,chrome=1
RESPONSE_BODY:
{
  "code": 600,
  "description": "Not enough memory capacity, you're allowed: 2048M"
}

> > >

cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:156:in `handle_error_response'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:135:in`handle_response'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:85:in `request'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:74:in`put'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/model_magic.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in define_client_methods'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/model.rb:91:in`update!'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/app.rb:131:in `update!'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/app.rb:121:in`start!'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:173:in `start_helper'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:89:in`create_helper'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:28:in `open!'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:41:in`block in tunnel'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:40:in`tunnel'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:66:in `run'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:72:in`block in invoke'

What actions should I take to resolve this?

To offer further background below are a few details about the env. my app is running in:

vmc stats logoff
Using manifest file manifest.yml

Getting stats for logoff... OK

instance   cpu    memory        disk

## 0         0.1%   74.2K of 2G   63.3M of 2G

vmc env logoff
Using manifest file manifest.yml

Getting env for logoff... OK

vmc services
Getting services... OK

name            service   version
mysql-service   mysql     5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have used all of your allotted 2Gb of RAM. To tunnel to a service, vmc needs to deploy a small Ruby application called Caldecott, this uses 64Mb. So in short, you need to free up 64Mb!

Comment: So I need to decrease the memory allocated to my app on the cloudfoundry infrastructure from 2GB? Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Decreasing the memory allocated to my app fixed the issue. Thanks! I don't know why I didn't logically try this approach.